# How to sort questions by answer count & Views

Tags: support, sorting

Can I sort tagged questions by answer count & Views?

Currently I can find `[android] views:5000` but I want know if I can sort by answer count also?

So that I can answer most viewed & unanswered question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't sort on answercount on the site.

You can use a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885025?tagname=android&viewcount=5000) if your use case allows for data to be up to 7 days stale (SEDE is only refreshed on Sunday).

For completeness here is the query:

```sql
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , answercount
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.tagname = 'android' 
where viewcount >= 5000
and closeddate is not null
order by p.answercount asc -- or desc if you want the high answers first
```

If you're new to SEDE consider the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial).

If you're only interested in unanswered questions with a high viewcount use this search

> [`[android] is:q answers:0 views:5000`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A0+views%3A5000&mixed=0)

that will give you questions in the android tag with 0 answers and 5000 or more views.

Notice how you can apply other search operators:

> [`[android] is:q answers:1..1 views:5000`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A1..1+views%3A5000&mixed=0)

to only find a question with 1 answer, or even questions that are not closed, have a single answer that isn't accepted:

> [`[android] is:q answers:1..1 hasaccepted:no closed:no views:5000`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+is%3Aq+answers%3A1..1+hasaccepted%3Ano+closed%3Ano+views%3A5000)

See the Help on [Searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for all the search operators and their possible usage.